# react native - how to use stackNavigator and DrawerNavigator together

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation-drawer

I am trying to use react native DrawerNavigator and StackNavigator together but for some reason I can't make it work.

Below is my code:

```
import {DrawerNavigator,StackNavigator, } from 'react-navigation'

class App extends Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <View style={{flex:1,backgroundColor:'transparent'}}>
        <AppStackNavigator/>
        <AppDrawerNavigator/>
       </View>
    )
  }
}

const AppDrawerNavigator = DrawerNavigator({
  Home:HomeScreen,
  Price:PriceScreen,
  Info:InfoScreen,
  Login:LoginScreen
})

const  AppStackNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Home:HomeScreen,
  Price:PriceScreen,
  Info:InfoScreen,
  Login:LoginScreen
})

export default App
```

When I run this code my app screen is split into half, top have shows `stackNavigator` screen and the bottom half shows `DrawerNavigator` screen.
Is there a way I can make these two work together?

Also, what is the difference between `stackNavigator` and `createStack Navigator`? I don't see the diffence when I run these.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to nest the Navigators to get the result you are asking for. 
For example if you want a stack navigation inside one of the screens in your drawer navigation you can do this:

```
import {DrawerNavigator, StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation'
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}>
                <AppDrawerNavigator />
            </View>
        )
    }
}

const AppStackNavigator = StackNavigator({
    Home: HomeScreen,
    Price: PriceScreen,
    Info: InfoScreen,
    Login: LoginScreen
})

const AppDrawerNavigator = DrawerNavigator({
    Home: AppStackNavigator,
    // Price: PriceScreen,
    // Info: InfoScreen,
    // Login: LoginScreen
})

 export default App
```

The important part is

```
const AppDrawerNavigator = DrawerNavigator({
    Home: AppStackNavigator, <--- This
    // Price: PriceScreen,
    // Info: InfoScreen,
    // Login: LoginScreen
})
```

Now the "Home" Screen in your Drawer Navigation has the ability to use the stack navigation. You can do this for the others screens as well.

Comment: Wow it works great thank you! btw you have any idea what is the diffenece between `createStackNavigator` and `StackNavigaor`?

Comment: i guess the StackNavigaor is the class and createStackNavigator is a method used to create a new StackNavigator