# Handling Back Navigation in Drawer Navigator in React Navigation

Tags: android, react-native

I have successfully created a navigation drawer in my app using React Navigation V3. But the problem occurs when after I open two pages using the drawer, on single back press, the page redirects to the home page directly and not the previous page.

I expect the app flow to be like that of stacknavigator but back() function is also not available in drawernavigator. Here is my drawer navigator:

```
const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
    Home: {
        screen:HomeScreen
    },
    Events: {
      screen: EventsScreen
    },
    Waste: {
      screen: ReportWasteScreen
    }
  },
  DrawerConfig
);
```

How can I modify the code so that when I open waste screen after opening events screen, on single back press, the page should redirect to events screen and not the home screen?

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/backhandler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution using this the answer in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52290534/react-native-how-to-use-stacknavigator-and-drawernavigator-together).

```
import {createDrawerNavigator, createStackNavigator, createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation'
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}>
                <AppDrawerNavigator />
            </View>
        )
    }
}

const AppStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Home: HomeScreen,
    Events: EventsScreen,
    Waste: WasteScreen
});

const AppDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
    Home: AppStackNavigator
});

export default createAppContainer(AppDrawerNavigator);
```

This solution creates a stack navigator inside a drawer navigator which makes the link click in drawer navigator open up a new page each time. Back handling is done automatically here.

Additionally, in order to remove the default header of the stack navigator, I added the following code:

```
{
  headerMode:'none',
  navigationOptions: {
    headerVisible: false,
  }
}
```

to the `AppStackNavigator`

Answer (score 0):

Use the "BackHandler" event to customize the routing

Comment: I found a solution using stack navigator inside drawer navigator. Please have a look at the answer I posted! Thank you! :)